How to install Safari browser in Ubuntu 22.04?
I'm getting an error which only reproduces on the Safari browser but I do development on Ubuntu and I'm not able to get a Mac laptop right now.
so the only option I have now is to install Safari in Ubuntu.
How can I do that?

You don't. They don't have any releases for Linux, and the ones they have for Windows are several years old (over a decade, I think). You could try installing that antique version using Wine, but web development has evolved so much since then that you might as well be running some other browser altogether.

Or if you really need Safari, you could run macOS in a VM. A bit involved, but hey.

The easiest way to replicate Safari's behavior, at least to some extent, would be to use Epiphany (now Gnome Web) browser. It is based on Webkit, and so the behavior should remain the same for most part.
